# Verifying if Key Values of Redis(Jedis) are JSON

Tags: java, json, database, redis, jedis

I'm trying to make a Java program that iterate over Redis database, veryfing the key values; if it's a valid JSON, extract into a separate schema(nothing done about this yet); else, do nothing, but keep searching over the other keys.

Here's my function code:

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");

    ScanResult<String> scanResult = jedis.scan("0");
    List<String> keys = scanResult.getResult();
    String nextCursor = scanResult.getStringCursor();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    int counter = 0;

    while(true) {

        if(nextCursor.equals("0")) {
            break;
        }

        scanResult = jedis.scan(nextCursor);
        nextCursor = scanResult.getStringCursor();
        keys = scanResult.getResult();
        for(counter = 0; counter <= keys.size(); counter++) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(keys.get(counter).toString());

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        System.out.println(keys = scanResult.getResult());
    }
    jedis.close();
```

I'm getting trouble with JSON Parse (idk if I'm using him correctly) because I think I'm only getting the KEY NAMES (not their values). 
I tried to use  `Map<String, String> = scanResult.getResult()` instead of `List<String>`, but it point out a Typemismatch problem.

Seems like easy to solve, but I'm kinda stuck at this point... Any tip that could help will be welcome, thanks.

P.S.: I cannot use modules like ReJSON, must be with native redis functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. Answering my own question:

```
public void readRedis() {
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");

    ScanResult<String> scanResult = jedis.scan("0");
    String nextCursor = scanResult.getStringCursor();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    int counter = 0;

    while (true) {
        nextCursor = scanResult.getStringCursor();
        List<String> keys = scanResult.getResult();
        for (counter = 0; counter < keys.size(); counter++) {
            if(counter == keys.size()) {
                break;
            }               
            try {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jedis.rpop(keys.get(counter)));
                documentoJson(json);                    
                System.out.println("Added to function 'documentoJson'");

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid JSON");
            }
        }
        if (nextCursor.equals("0")) {
            break;
        }
        scanResult = jedis.scan(nextCursor);
    }
    jedis.close();
}

public JSONArray documentoJson(JSONObject json) {
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    jArray.add(json);
    jObject.put("JSON Document", jArray);
    return jArray;
 }
```